# How to setup nodatime json serializer in asp.net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, nodatime

I try to figure out how to setup NodaTime JSON serialization in ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web Api project.
The way it is described [here](https://nodatime.org/3.0.x/userguide/serialization) doesn't work for me

```
services.AddJsonFormatters(settings => settings.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb));
```

because there is no such method as `AddJsonFormatters` on `services : IServiceCollection`.
Installed packages:

```
NodaTime v 3.0.3  
NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet v 3.0.0
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson v 3.1.9
Newtonsoft.Json v 12.0.3
```

Could you help me with this, please? What method should I use in Startup.cs to configure NodaTime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was looking for the `JsonSerializerSettings` class that has the needed extension method `ConfigureForNodaTime()` and found it in `SerializerSettings` field of `MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions` and configured it as below:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(s =>
    s.SerializerSettings.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb));
```

Comment: since asp net core 3 the default json serializer is System.Text.Json and not Newtonsoft Json. Is this setup adding both serializers?

Answer (score 3):

Add Nuget Package "NodaTime.Serialization.SystemTextJson"

then do the following

```
 using NodaTime.Serialization.SystemTextJson;
```

....

```
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {               
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
        });
```